# How to pronounce 翁 in Mainland China and Taiwan?

Tags: difference

I ran into a book talking about the difference of pronouncing 翁 in Mainland China and Taiwan differently. But it is still confusing to me. My questions are:

What is the difference of pronouncing 翁 in Mainland China and Taiwan?

How to pronounce 翁 in Mainland China and Taiwan?

Comment: Can you post what that book says about this in your question? I'm unaware that there is a difference.

Comment: @Semaphore yes there's a minor difference. I feel Taiwanese people pronounce it like `wēong`; and the mainland people, a "pure" `wēng`.

Comment: In Mainland China it is spelled as 'weng', and in Taiwan it is 'wong'

Comment: I believe the Pinyin spelling “weng” instead of “ong” is irrelevant to its pronunciation, merely in an attempt to reduce the need of apostrophe (').

Answer (score 4):

This concerns a mid-back vowel pair of [ɤ]/[o] (in IPA symbol), where [ɤ] is unrounded and [o] rounded. In today's mandarin in China, it's unrounded; in taiwan, it is sometimes rounded and sometimes unrounded, depending on the preceding consonant. If the preceding consonant is labial then pinyin o is the rounded [o], otherwise the unrounded [ɤ]. The Taiwanese pronunciation was also the older mandarin pronunciation and can still be heard in many regions' accents in China, but not in today's standard mandarin any more.